# Should data attribute of object tag be percent-encoded?

Tags: html, url, object-tag, percent-encoding, custom-data-attribute

Suppose my web application renders the following tag:

```
<object type="application/x-pdf" data="http://example.com/test%2Ctest.pdf">
     <param name="showTableOfContents" value="true" />
     <param name="hideThumbnails" value="false" />
</object>
```

Should `data` attribute be escaped (percent-encoded path) or no? In my example it is. I haven't found any specification.

**addendum**

Actually, I'm interested in specification on what should browser plugins consuming `data` attribute expect to see there. For example, Adobe Acrobat plugin takes both escaped and unescaped uri. However, [QWebPluginFactory](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwebpluginfactory.html) treats `data` attribute as a human readable URI (unescaped), and that leads to double percent encoding. And I'm wondering whether it is a bug of `QWebPluginFactory` or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`data` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#adef-data) expects the value to be a URI. So you should provide a value that is a syntactically valid URI.

The current specification of URIs is [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). To see whether the `,` in the URI’s path needs to be encoded, take a look at how the *path* production rule is defined:

> ```
> path          = path-abempty    ; begins with "/" or is empty
>               / path-absolute   ; begins with "/" but not "//"
>               / path-noscheme   ; begins with a non-colon segment
>               / path-rootless   ; begins with a segment
>               / path-empty      ; zero characters
> ```

Since we have a URI with *authority* information, we need to take a look at *path-abempty* (see [*URI* production rule](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3)):

> ```
> path-abempty  = *( "/" segment )
> ```

*segment* is zero or more *pchar* characters that is defined as follows (I’ve already expanded the production rules):

```
pchar         = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~" / "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG / "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")" / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "=" / ":" / "@"
```

And as you can see, *pchar* expands to a literal `,`. So you don’t need to encode the `,` in the *path* component. But since you are allowed to encode any non-delimiting character using the percent-encoding without changing its meaning, it is fine to use `%2C` instead of `,`.

Comment: Accepting this answer since it points out the most important thing: `data` attribute is an URI according to the specification.

Answer (score 0):

URLs generally can only contain specific characters. Unfortunately different specifications contain different lists of characters that are considered reserved and thus can't be used.

In your example the encoded character is a comma (`,`), which is a reserved character in some specifications, so it's not wrong to encode it.

Most webservers should handle unencoded and encoded commas equaly, however there can be some that don't, depending on their configuration. Due to that it is generally a good idea to avoid having special characters in filenames (as you have in your example) in the first place.

URL encoding is always needed when you have special characters in GET parameters. For example a GET parameter that is support to take `C&A` as a value has to be written as:

```
http://example.com/somescript.php?value=C%26A
```

---

**EDIT:**

Plugins (or even the browser) don't care either way. They don't try to (or need to) decode it or anything like that. They just request the URL as entered from the server.

Comment: Actually, I'm interested in specification on what do browser plugins consuming `data` attribute expect to see there. I'll expand my question.